# Get input values from backend form [octobercms]

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

Everything is working fine in this code except `$result = Input::get('term');` Someone please help me to get the input value of field `term`. When i  do this `$result = 8;` everything works well.

[Form in plugin backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4X3e.png)

**In my plugin "Lesson" model**

```
<?php

 namespace Cng\Tennis\Models;

 use Model;
 use Flash;
 use Db;
 use Input;
 use request;
 use Cng\Tennis\Models\Term as termModel;

 class Lesson extends Model
 {  
public function getSdateOptions () {

  $result = Input::get('term');
  $term = termModel::select('id','start_date')->where('id',  $result )->first();

   if ($this->term_id == $result ) { 
        return [$term->id => $term->start_date];   
    }
    else{
      return ['Select a date' => 'Select a date' ];
      }
    }

public function getFdateOptions () {
        return ['Select a date' => 'Select a date' ];
    }
```

**In yaml**

```
    term:
        label: Term
        nameFrom: name
        descriptionFrom: description
        span: auto
        containerAttributes: {  }
        type: dropdown
        emptyOption: Select
        tab: 'Event Details'
        dependsOn:
            - location

    sdate:
        label: 'Start Date'
        mode: date
        span: left1
        cssClass: ''
        required: 1
        dependsOn:
            - term
        type: dropdown
        tab: 'Event Details'
        disabled: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your problem is caused by the fact that the `term` field is not named that in the HTML. If you look at the generated form inputs in the browser, or in the AJAX request that's sent when the `dependsOn` trigger is fired, you'll notice that the actual field name for the `term` field is prefixed with the Form widget's alias (probably `Form`, so in this case the actual field name is `Form[term]`).

However, you don't even have to use `Input` at all, you can just reference the model property the `term` field refers to directly in your function:

```
$options = [0 => 'Select a start date'];
$term = TermModel::find($this->term);

if ($term) {
    $options = [$term->id => $term->start_date];
}

return $options;
```

See https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-dependencies for more information on how to properly utilize the `dependsOn` property. Note that you could probably combine it in your case with the `trigger` property to also hide the `start_date` field until you have a valid option selected in the `term` field.

Comment: Great!!  Thank you very much Luke!. Like you said generated form inputs in the browser was named like "Lesson[term]" So all I have to do is adding this line $term= post('Lesson[term]');  everything is working fine.

Comment: I think you missed the part where I said that you could just do `$this->term` instead. That would be the more correct way of accessing that value.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the `select('id','start_date')` with `all()` or `find($result)` and if you only want to grab the start date do `pluck->('start_date')`. Seems you can't use select on eloquent models which makes sense in my test.

This is what I get when I run select without the DB call:

```
    $names = Products::select('id','name')->where('id', 1);
    return $names;
```

[image]

However when I access the model by normal collection query methods I get this:

```
    $names = Products::all()->where('id', 1);
    return $names;
```

[image]

Lastly you can just use `$names = Products::find('1')->pluck('name')->first();` replace `1` with `$result` and `'name'` with `'start_date'` in your case.

Comment: The problem the original poster is running into isn't a problem with the query, it's a problem with getting the user's input to plug into the query.

Comment: @Luke yep problem with getting the user's input.

Comment: @Pettis Thanks for your time anyway :) !!